# My footer doesn't stay where it should be

Tags: html, css

I don't know why this is not working and it's driving me crazy. The footer is not sticking to the bottom of the site. In the views of my app where the content is not longer that the viewport the footer is sticking well, but when the content is longer, the footer stays at the bottom of the viewport instead of at the bottom of the page.

I've set the position as absolute and the bottom as 0. Also I've set the containing element, which is the body, as position relative so that the footer absolute position is relative to the body, but it doesn't work either way.

Here's the code (I've separated the header and footer partials of every view of my app, but it works as if it was one file)

CSS CODE

```
body {
position: relative;}

.footer {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
min-height: 50px;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `position: absolute;`, you've taken your footer out of the normal document flow. The layout isn't leaving any space for it so as the length of your content increases, an overlap is going to appear.

The layout issue you're trying to resolve is incredibly common and there are tried and tested ways of dealing with it. Many solutions require you to know the height of the footer which is rarely practical. If you knew the footer was always going to be 100px for example, you could simply set padding-bottom on body in order to add the necessary space.

## Flexbox

Thanks to flexbox, there's an easy approach that doesn't require you to know the height of the footer element.

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <header role="banner">Site Header</header>
        <main>Content</main>
        <footer role="contentinfo">Footer</footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

header[role="banner"],
footer[role="contentinfo"] {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}

main {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

By telling `main` to occupy all of the remaining space (`flex: 1 1 auto`) in the flex container (`body`), you're going to push the footer to the bottom of the page.